# Java multithread vs Shell script

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, shell, jakarta-ee

If i have 3 tasks that i want to run all of them simultaneously, there are two ways i'm thinking of right now.

Since i'm running the program in linux, i could do it in shell script.

> ```
>   java Task1 &
>   java Task2 &
>   java Task3 &
> ```

or, i could use one java program to spawn three child threads to do the tasks.

I want to know which way is more efficient. I doubt the shell way will create multiple JVM instance?

Comment: Of course the shell script will create multiple JVM instances - that's what you tell it to do. If the tasks you're trying to accomplish are independent (they don't require communication with each other) the shell script is the easiest way (and the one that makes the most sense).

Comment: As to more efficient it depends on what you mean by efficient - less memory use, swap space, execution time, disk access, programming time, safety etc.... and also what the code does

Comment: Just remember that if you do it with multiple threads within one JVM, you're going to have static variables and such like shared between the threads.  Without knowing your application, I can't say whether that would be a problem, but it's something you need to consider.  If you have three separate JVMs, then each will have its own static variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the tasks run for a long time, the overhead of three JVMs is negligible:

- Loading times / disk access is no issue due to filesystem caching.
- The shared library memory is singleton within the Linux kernel. I assume Java uses per-thread garbage collectors resulting in the same amount of default memory allocated for three threads as compared to three JVMs (except minimal JVM metadata memory).
- It is also a well-known fact that Linux is very efficient in process scheduling, making independent forks of a daemon at least as efficient as multiple threads. Under Windows we have a different situation where process instantiation is an expensive operation.

With a long time I refer to 30 seconds up per-task. Now what about short-time tasks? Here time-efficiency is only important if the task is repeated very often. Repeated runs have a much smaller overhead of (re-)loading the JVM, but there is always some that is going to stay.

**Verdict:** Using the shell script is much easier to implement, less code to write and maintain und much more configurable without writing even more code. And during run-time, in a common scenario, you will observe no big differences between the two approaches.

Answer (score 4):

It would be more efficient to do this in Java, make your program multithreaded and use three threads. Yes, the shell way will create three JVM instances.

But the question is, why should you consider one alternative over the other? If this is only a small task anyway, I would personally simply start three instances in the shell as you did.

Comment: It could take longer to program and be more error prone which could be they way efficiency is measured.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing it now launches three separate JVM instances, each dedicated to one task. If you want to run all three tasks concurently on one JVM, you need to create Thread objects for them.

So I would create one very simple Java program which would launch these tasks each in its own thread. Then I would convert that program to a .jar file and schedule it for execution.

Comment: How do you know how you would solve the problem if you don't even know what exactly he wants to do? For all we know he could try to run a http server along with a sudoku client.

Comment: @Cubic He ased for difference between those two, and I tried to answer. The rest is up to him to figure out. Or he can edit the question or ask a new one if the matter is still unclear to him.

Answer (score 0):

the More JVM the more cpu time. Since three Thread on one JVM would be better. But It is worth to make simple benchmarking test. If you do, please share it with us.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know which way is more efficient.

If you just restrict your criteria for deciding to processor efficiency, the Java threads approach is *most likely* to more efficient.  The overheads of running the extra JVMs in terms of JVM startup, and memory utilization will be appreciable.

The only scenarios in which the multithreaded version might be slower involve either competition between the tasks for some resource or poor choice of JVM tuning options; e.g. if you make the heap too small.

However, I don't think that deciding purely on the grounds of processor efficiency is wise:

- If the tasks are long running and you have enough memory for the 3 JVMs, the performance difference (in percentage terms) could be insignificant.  (Who cares if you take 10 seconds longer to start the JVMs if the entire run takes 10 hours!)
- You also need to consider development time, testing and maintenance.  Your thinking needs to factor in the potential complexity of writing a robust multi-threaded application.  (And I can't predict that without more details of your system's functional and non-functional requirements.)

In summary, there is no good definite answer without more details of your problem, etc

---

> I doubt the shell way will create multiple JVM instance?

Wrong.  It **will** create multiple JVM instances.